# Get keyCode 0 instead of 66 when Enter is pressed on my computer keyboard

Tags: android, keyevent, enter

I have a simple activity with a EditText. I want to save the form data when the user enters a name into the EditText and then hits Enter.

Everything works find except one thing. The keyCode variable is 0 instead of 66 (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER).

Does anyone have any idéa of what the problem is?

My layout xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    style="@style/EditTextFont"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

My Activity:

```
private EditText etName;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.form);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etName.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.etName:
      // actionId will be EditorInfo.IME_NULL if being called 
      // due to the enter key being pressed.
      if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && 
            (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL)) {
         save();
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Regards, Mattias

Comment: what do you mean by The keyCode variable is 0 instead of 66? Your code is working or not ?

Comment: Because keyCode is 0 the code in the if statement will not be executed. The method onEditorAction is called when I hit enter in the EditText, the only problem is that the keyCode is not 66 as I would have expected.

Comment: Although impolite, Yves Daoust was actually correct in his answer. I had mixed up two different methods. I corrected the solution above. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try with SDK's Enter key instead of using Computer's keyboard key.

Comment: Running on WXGA800 (to simulate a tablet) on Android 4.0.3 which doesn't display a keyboard on screen. But thanks for the suggestion. Problem solved anyway, see my comment to my original question.

Comment: Though your issue is solved, you can test this once in Android 3.0 environment sdk tablet. Which displays the emulator keyboard after switching on Physical Keyboard option.